# How to remove registers that there are a specific empty cell? - MDX - Pentaho

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, pentaho, mondrian

Im newbie in MDX, I need to remove all registers from my result that the field *solvedate_id*, from my fact table called Ticket, is null.

Any idea?

Follow there is the code that brings all registers:

*select*

NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Ticket id]} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY Order({([Dimgroup.Grupo].[All Dimgroup.Grupos], 
[Dimstatus.Status].[All Dimstatus.Statuss], 
[Dimtempoabertura.AnoAbertura].[All Dimtempoabertura.AnoAberturas], [Dimtempoabertura.MesAbertura].[All Dimtempoabertura.MesAberturas])}, 
[Measures].[Ticket id], ASC) ON ROWS

from [GLPI]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question at all

Comment: For example, I have two registers:

Id Name Status 
1  John Enable
2  Mary Disable

I want to show only the Enabled users.

How can I filter just the registers with Enabled in the field Status?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a hierarchy for Registers with "status" which equates to the Enabled field.  Then simply add that to the MDX either in the whereclause or crossjoining on rows.

[Registers].[Enabled].[True]

(however it looks for you)